# Twitter Oath Token issue

Tags: php, twitter-oauth

I am receive the follwoing error below and I am not sure why it is not receiving a token.

Whoa there!
There is no request token for this page. That's the special key we need from applications asking to use your Twitter account. Please go back to the site or application that sent you here and try again; it was probably just a mistake.

The url: https://twitter.com/oauth/authorize?oauth_token=

```
  include_once 'classes/lib/EpiCurl.php';
include_once 'classes/lib/EpiOAuth.php';
include_once 'classes/lib/EpiTwitter.php';
include_once 'classes/lib/secret.php';


if (!isset($_GET['oauth_token'])) $_GET['oauth_token'] = "";
if (!isset($_GET['bm'])) $_GET['bm'] = "";
if (!isset($_GET['next'])) $_GET['next'] = "";
if (!isset($_POST['login'])) $_POST['login'] = "";

$twitterObj = new EpiTwitter($consumer_key, $consumer_secret);
$oauth_token = $_GET['oauth_token'];    

  if($oauth_token == '')
  { 
    $tloginurl = $twitterObj->getAuthorizationUrl();        
}
```

Comment: Check twitter documentation, I remember they changed the oauth part to api.twitter.com

Comment: @SorinTrimbitas I am not sure what you mean? This was working.

Comment: What i told you was from my own experience .. it happened few months ago for me, things using twitter API just stopped working and after changing it .. it worked  : https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/oauth/authorize

Comment: @SorinTrimbitas I have those set correctly but it is still not work.

Comment: From your own answer : "The url: https://twitter.com/oauth/authorize?oauth_token=" .. you corrected it?

Comment: @SorinTrimbitas yes, i did I a receive this same thing.